# Why have I stopped earning reputation for upvotes?

Tags: support, answers, reputation, upvotes, daily-reputation-limit

I answered a question and got +30 for the first 3 upvotes. Then I got another upvote, but no more reputation. Why did I stop getting rep for upvotes?

Comment: You reached daily reputation cap.

Comment: See [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/168244)

Comment: Shouldn't the reputation cap be removed for answers you added that day? I mean, if you give a reputation cap, then users won't be motivated to answer questions after they hit the 200 cap.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. If it was, users like Jon Skeet would have got 5 million reputation points by now. Also, reputation can increase beyond the cap after the answers are accepted or if you earn any bounties. If you feel like not answering because of reputation not getting increased, you can try answering community wiki, which will help *most* users edit the answer and thus making it better.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seems like a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @RobertKarl this is common knowledge among veteran users, and has been for a long, long time. There are posts about it all over [meta.se], the old Meta Stack Overflow. Plus, as [icktoofay points out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251419/456814), it's also in the help center.

Comment: @Shog9 you don't want to turn this into a FAQ post or something?

Comment: @RobertKarl: I didn't downvote, but it's probably for the same reason that many other questions get downvoted - lack of research effort. In this case, the answer is found by simply visiting the SO [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how reputation works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You hit the reputation cap of 200 reputation points per day.<sup>1</sup> See [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) for more information.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are some exceptions to this cap. If you care, read the article linked above.

Comment: Thank you... I had read the article before but was under the impression that new answers for the day are considered under exceptions. Just re-read it. Wish that person had waited for the next day to upvote lol